# How to target div#specificDiv in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask that how can i target a specific division in Jquery code. In the code below we are targeting "everything", Even if we change this to "div", it will target all the divisions in the file.But my question is that how can we target a specific division, As i want to target at the div with class "particles particles2"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $('body').jGravity({
      target: 'eveything',
      ignoreClass: 'ignoreMe',
      weight: 25,
      depth: 5,
      drag: true
    });
    // Misc code for demo purposes
    $(this).removeClass('#fountains');

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="template-page"> </div>
<div class="particles particles2 ignoreMe jGravity" id="fountains"></div>
```

Comment: If I understand your question, [you don't even need jQuery for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Read this: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Explaining it, I am using Mr. Doob Gravity library, and i want to target specific division for that. Please use the library and target specific div from a collection of divs and show an example if possible.

Comment: Click the target is? ‍‍`$(document).on('click', function()`

Comment: Read this link: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For targeting specific Div with class define selectors as div.class, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', function() {
        $('body').jGravity({
            target: 'div.particles',
            ignoreClass: 'ignoreMe',
            weight: 25,
            depth: 5,
            drag: true
        });
        // Misc code for demo purposes
        $(this).removeClass('#fountains');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a small snippet that will help you understand how selectors work:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.particles', function() {
  // code here that should be executed when particles div is clicked.
  alert("You clicked me!");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="particles">Click</div>
```

When you click on the 'click', an alert would be popped up, but if you click anywhere in the document, nothing happens. That's because, in JQuery, we have mentioned that the click event should get fired on the click on ".particles", which is the class of the div.

If you want to use IDs, you need to use '#'. Example:
`$("#ID_OF_THE_CONTAINER")`

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click',".particles", function() {
        /*$('body').jGravity({
            target: 'eveything',
            ignoreClass: 'ignoreMe',
            weight: 25,
            depth: 5,
            drag: true
        });
        // Misc code for demo purposes
        $(this).removeClass('#fountains');*/
        console.log("Test Click!");
    });
});
```

```css
.particles{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="particles particles2 ignoreMe jGravity" id="fountains">Click me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a specific class, put the selector in `target:`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', function() {
        $('body').jGravity({
            target: '.particles.particles2',
            ignoreClass: 'ignoreMe',
            weight: 25,
            depth: 5,
            drag: true
        });
        // Misc code for demo purposes
        $(this).removeClass('#fountains');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case :

```
$("div.particles.particles2")
```

...will access the specific div tag you want.